# How would I go about making a bot that counts how many peoples name starts with a '5' in a voice channel (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a bot that tells you how many people are in a voice channel that have their knickname start with a '5' and does @everyone if there are less than 6 people that are in a voice channel with their knicknames starting with 5. If you understand that. I dont even know where to start.

Comment: Get the channel from its id and then you can list the members with `https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.voice_states`.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to get the `VoiceChannel` object from the command invocation, and then use that to look at the display names of the members inside that channel.

```
from discord import VoiceChannel
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@bot.command()
async def count_fives(ctx, channel: VoiceChannel):
    num_fives = sum(member.display_name.startswith("5") for member in channel.members)
    if num_fives < 6:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.guild.default_role} there are not enough people in the channel.")

bot.run("token")
```